# SET String value To Scalar Variable HSQLDB

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I tried like below;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetHs(IN FRVDate TIMESTAMP, IN TRVDate TIMESTAMP, IN RESValue NUMERIC(19,2),
RangeType VARCHAR(20), HRID VARCHAR(36)) 
READS SQL DATA
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
        BEGIN ATOMIC
            DECLARE TABLE myList(MValue NUMERIC(19,2), Price NUMERIC(19,2), FRVDate TIMESTAMP,TRVDate TIMESTAMP);
            DECLARE Counter INT;
            DECLARE dateDifference NUMERIC(19,2);
            DECLARE for_day,for_week VARCHAR(20);

            SET for_day = 'DAY';
            SET for_week = 'WEEK';

                IF RangeType = for_day THEN
                    BEGIN ATOMIC
                     ----statements----
                    END
                    ELSEIF RangeType = for_week THEN
                    BEGIN ATOMIC
                     ----statements----
                    END
                END IF
                SELECT MValue,Price,FRVDate,TRVDate FROM myList
        END
```

I get error that `user lacks privilege or object not found: DAY`. Can i not set values to Declared scalar variables?

In Documentation it says to use in this format. From DOC;

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
 DECLARE temp_zero DATE;
 DECLARE temp_one, temp_two INTEGER DEFAULT 2;
 DECLARE temp_three VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'no name';
 -- more statements ...
 SET temp_zero = DATE '2010-03-18';
 SET temp_two = 5;
 -- more statements ...
END
```

Whats i am doing wrong here?

**NOTE: Started Learning HSQL Recently and Using version 2.3.3**

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy paste error. Now fixed.

Comment: Use the latest HSQLDB snapshot version for learning. It has improved support for procedures.

Comment: @fredt : Tried that and no more errors. Thanks! Please post this answer so i can mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest HSQLDB code. The next version 2.4.0 supports it. A snapshot of the next version is currently available at http://hsqldb.org/support